# What kind of soldering material is this?

Tags: soldering

I just saw a video of this gray goo that basically auto-solders small electronic components.  I was wondering what this is, and where I can get some.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't really "auto solder", it's the flux and capillary force doing it and that works the same as when soldering with an iron, if done correctly. Solder paste is pretty much the only sensible way to solder heatsink IC, as in this picture. But there are downsides with hot air, namely that it is very easy to "blow away" surrounding components by accident, like those passives nearby. Personally I like to solder heatsink components and large IC the first thing I do on the board, so I don't mess up the surroundings by accident.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is solder paste - a combination of flux and suspended solder. When heated (e.g. with hot air) it melts; thanks to the wetting behavior of the pads vs the solder mask, surface tension tends to pull it toward the pads, showing the  "auto-solder" behavior on a suitably designed board.

It often comes in either small jars, or in syringe style tubes with plungers that can be attached to a dispensing needle. Your image shows an example of the latter. In many cases, the tube-style containers can also be attached to powered dispensers as an alternative to operating the tube plunger by hand.

Of course, solder paste is not magic - you do need to be "close enough" with device placement, and various assembly issues (e.g. tombstoning, shorts, etc) can happen with subpar technique or materials. The board design and materials are also important - after all, it's the surface tension on vs off the pads board that causes parts to pull into position as that image shows.

You also need to be attentive to storage - the solder pastes I've used tend to require refrigeration and may not last too long once opened.

This site isn't a good fit for shopping recommendations; the best source depends on your country, available vendors, order size, shipping needs, etc. It's also likely to vary over time, so shopping recs in answers would become out of date. An electronics distributor that you trust to buy parts is a good first place to check.

As Scott Seidman points out in the comments, workability depends on the exact solder composition you select. While lead-free pastes are good for environmental compliance and avoid lead contamination from mass manufacturing, they're a bit harder to work with and require higher temperatures. The easiest for hobby use is standard 60/40 or 63/37 metal composition (roughly 60% tin and 40% lead) that matches the composition of the standard hobby solder you'll find on a spool, but since it contains lead, it has environmental considerations and may not be suitable for products you repair or sell.

The material is likewise engineered for mass reflow fabrication, commonly done with custom-cut solder stencils, and isn't optimized for  hobby usage, although it is still definitely usable at hobby scale with a suitable set of work techniques.

Comment: Nice synopsis.  I'd add that if the OP wants to get into this, they should go for lead and avoid lead-free options, as they require higher temperatures that make the process more difficult for hobbyists.  Also, the pastes are pretty much to support industrial reflow processes, and that most other uses, while they can be very successful, are largely "hacks"

Comment: @Nelson:  Keep in mind that there's soldering paste for reflow soldering (the stuff containing flux and solder) and there's other stuff also called soldering paste that contains only flux (and often times a really nasty flux intended for plumbing instead of electronics.)

Comment: I'd also suggest adding some details about the shelf-life, especially after opening, as they don't last very long unsealed. I don't use paste much, but I've gotten the impression from coworkers who do that a syringe of paste should generally be used within one or two weeks of first opening it.

Comment: @Hearth I've had mixed experiences myself, having used old paste due to limited budget and a painful process for ordering consumables for that lab. With good refrigeration and attention to how we opened and sealed the container (avoiding air bubbles, tightly capping, purging a bit of material from the nozzle), I was able to get decent performance even after those few weeks. It wasn't amazing, but it still worked passably for that basic hobby/one-off use.

Comment: You can't ask for shopping recommendations, if it's a solution to a problem you can recommend whatever the solution is.

Comment: @VoltageSpike I think I'm missing context for your comment - as far as I can tell I've addressed the non shopping parts and discussed the solution (solder paste) without vendor details. Was that in response to a now-deleted comment that I can't see?

Comment: Whether to use leaded or RoHS solder depends on if the product is to be placed on the market or not. Leaded solder is ok to use for hobbyist boards or prototypes that will eventually end up in electronics recycling anyway. But you can't use leaded solder when repairing commercial products. There's no telling what background the OP has, so we shouldn't propose leaded solder without any context.

Comment: I agree with @Lundin - personally I use lead-free in my projects, because I also use it in repairs and in work (university research, though I was in industry when ROHS came in).  A cheap temperature controlled iron makes a big difference when using lead-free - the old Weller 15W toolbox irons aren't really up to the job.

Comment: @Lundin -- my understanding is that repair operations are RoHS exempt (https://www.reliableplant.com/Read/2130/maintenance-engineer-rohs) (as are all medical products in the US, as an aside), but correct me if this isn't true.  My own experience with rework and hand assembly is that lead is a good deal easier, on every iron I've used, from cheap Hakko to Metcal stations -- especially to learn with.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Everybody who I've encountered who hates lead-free uses poor technique overall. They're the guys who turn the iron up to 800 F to start. Lead-free requires adjustments in production, where you stick the boards in the oven and thousands of joints must work perfectly at the other side. Lead-free requires little adjustments when hand soldering, as you're constantly monitoring and compensating anyway. If somebody is finding difficulty with lead-free solder, they need to look at their technique and maybe equipment, and not blame the solder.

Comment: @user71659 -- I didn't say I hated lead-free solder, just that it's more difficult to use.  Your comment is pretty much a testimonial to that, basically saying leaded solder is more forgiving to flawed technique.  I think "start with lead, if you can" is absolutely fine advice for someone asking "what's this gray goo".

Comment: @ScottSeidman That link is extremely outdated, looks like they were preparing for the first RoHS. And it is wrong. Article 4 of Directive 2011/65/EU: "_Member States shall ensure that EEE placed on the market, including cables and spare parts for its repair, its reuse, updating of its functionalities or upgrading of its capacity, does not contain the substances listed in Annex II._" Additionally there's WEEE and REACH to consider as well.

Comment: @ScottSeidman And of course leaded solder is way easier to work with, you have a melting point some 40°C lower. I always use leaded solder for hand soldering prototypes etc - it is not an issue to use it as long as you don't put the result on the market. My hand soldered prototypes eventually ends up in the electronics recycling.

Comment: @user71659 Conditions aren't always ideal. Quite often when you hand solder something, you are dealing with prototype PCBs which were not ideally drawn - they are prototypes. Quite often there is bad thermal relief. If the designer manages to get bad thermal relief on something like an IC heatsink, then there exists no way to solder it correctly by the book, no better technique will save you. In that case you try everything: preheating with heat plate, leaded solder paste and you crank the solder station temperature up as high as you dare.